# NLog Fatal message never logged?

Tags: nlog

I'm using NLog 4.7.10 in a C# console application. My Info, Error, and Warn messages appear in my log file as expected, but fatal messages never do. My code looks like:

```
NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

logger.Fatal("This never appears in the log file!");
logger.Info("This info message is logged in the log file.");
logger.Error("This error message is logged in the log file.");
logger.Warn("This warning message is logged in the log file.");
```

I don't think anything in my nlog.config is causing issues:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Warn"
      internalLogFile="d:\tmp\log.txt">

    <variable name="defaultLayout" value="${date:format=dd MMM yyyy HH\:mm\:ss} [${level}]: ${message:withException=true}" />

    <targets>
        <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/foo.log"
            archiveOldFileOnStartup="true"
            layout="${defaultLayout}"
            archiveFileName = "${basedir}/logs/archives/foo ${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss}.log"
            archiveNumbering = "Rolling" />
        <target name="console" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" layout="${defaultLayout}" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

What might filter out the fatal messages?

Comment: Please create a new issue here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues where you attach a sample application that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Maybe check https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

I had found the issue. One of our functions whose purpose was to set the log file path (given a database value) had a side effect. It also set the maxiumum log level. In this case, it was setting the maximum log level to Error.

Sorry to bother.

Comment: Happy you found the cause of the mysterious behavior

Comment: I think this question should be removed from Stackoverflow. The issue is  somewhere else and I don't think others will have any benefits of the question (and answer) unfortunately

Comment: @Julian I'm unable to delete it. I get an error when atttempting to do so.